# gparted/ext4 - Shrink partition to encrypted filesystem previous size after failed "move right" operation

Tags: ext4, luks, gparted

After unsuccessfully try to "move right" large encrypted partition on my HDD, GParted show me this:
[image: gparted]

If I click on Partition > Information I have this message :

```
176.57 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
```

[image: information gparted]

After careful consideration, I finally want to recreate a new partition `sdb7` having size of 176.57 GiB (like before) and keep `sdb6` at original size (before failed operation).

**How I can easily SHRINK my partition to exact filesystem size ?** I found lot of resources to expand filesystem to partition size but not for shrinking... Important note is i'm using encrypted partition with luks....

I hesitate between multiple choices :

1. Gparted > Resize/Move but I don't know how to be sure operation will be quick, and exact size to setup.
2. Maybe `resize2fs -M /dev/sdb6` but I'm not sure it's the right option to use.

Here more information about my FS :

```
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              93634560
Block count:              374506240
Reserved block count:     18725312
Free blocks:              209754695
Free inodes:              88553316
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
```

Last detail : My GNU/Linux configuration is still booting like before (hopefully) so it's because I need to use sdb7 from my windows installation.

Comment: Regardless of what you, have backups.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Didn't make backup before to do "move right", I was on fire x) 14h process  during the night, but on morning Gparted live cd show me just black screen....Thanks for the advice, all my most importants files are already backup anyway ;)